# Function error 'expected expression before char'? I need more explanation

Tags: c

I have created the following program. I have not finished with the entire code yet. When I compile the program I get this error:

> 'expected expression before char'

on line 44.

Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
char** scan(FILE *fin, int *n);
void sort(char **array, int n);

void print(FILE *fout, char **array, int n);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
FILE *fp,*dat;
int n;
char **niz;
fp=fopen(argv[1],"r");
dat=fopen(argv[2],"w");

niz=scan(fp,&n);
printf("%d", n);
sort(niz,n);
print(dat,niz,n);

fclose(fp);
fclose(dat);
free(niz);
{

char** scan(FILE *fp, int *n)

{

int c,m=0,g=0;
char **niz;

niz=(char**)calloc(1,sizeof(char *));
niz[0]=(char*)calloc(21,sizeof(char));

while((c=fgetc(fp)!=EOF))
    {
        if((c>64 && c<91) || (c>96 && c<123))
            niz[m][g++]=c;
        else if(niz[m][0]!=0)
            {
                m++;
                g=0;
                niz=(char**)realloc(niz,(m+1)*sizeof(*char));
                niz[m]=(char*)calloc(21,sizeof(char));
            }
    }
    if(niz[m][0]==0)
        *n=m;
    else *n=m-1;
    return niz;
}
```

Comment: First off, please format your code properly. It’s currently impossible to decypher.

Comment: The error is much easier to see if the code is properly indented. Also you should mark the line in the code, so we don't have to count.

Comment: The brace after `free(niz);` needs to be a `}` instead of a `{`. `sizeof(*char)` needs to be  `sizeof(char*)`.

Comment: Do some [rubber duck debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) of your code. Go from the top (the first line in the file) down, and explain what each line does to your "rubber duck". I'm sure you'll be able to find the problem yourself then.

Comment: On an unrelated note, please don't use [magic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)). If you want to see if a character is a letter, use the [`isalpha`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/isalpha) function.

Comment: What's wrong with `free(niz); { char** scan(FILE *fp, int *n) {`? and `sizeof(*char)` -> `sizeof(char*)`

Answer (score 0):

Check the closing brace of the `main` function